# Why I get that x is not equal to 10?

Tags: python-2.7

```
import win32gui

def enumHandlerrr(hwnd, lParam):
   if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
       if 'Python' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
           x = 10;

x = ()          
win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandlerrr, None)
print (x)
```

when i run code i get that x =() and i need it to be 10

Comment: Please [read the documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32gui__EnumWindows_meth.html) and you'll understand why your code won't work (even with globals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import win32gui

def enumHandlerrr(hwnd, lParam):
   global x
   if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
       if 'Python' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
           x = 10

x = ()          
win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandlerrr, None)
print x
```

You need `global x` or else you only create a new local variable `x`. It won't write to variables in the global frame unless you do this.